# Query posts to show posts with todays date. Event date not post date

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, date, time

I need to query custom post to find all the posts that have todays date[these are events so not the date posted but the date the events are on]. This brings in all the posts according to when they were posted. The query must always bring in the current days events not just today specific. So if there are any events tomorrow it will bring the events fro tomorrow.

```
$args = (array('post_type' => 'ai1ec_event','order' => 'ASC','posts_per_page' => 3,'paged' => $paged));
query_posts( $args );
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$event = Ai1ec_Events_Helper::get_event($post->ID); 
    if(($event->start) >= time()) {
    $eevents[] = array("date" => $event->start, "link" =>get_permalink(),
            "title" =>get_the_title(),"time" => $event->get_timespan_html(), "venue" =>
    $event->venue, "event-img" => wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'tab_image'), "event-cont" => get_the_content(), "end" => $event->end);
}
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since start date is saved in wp_ai1ec_events table, you need to join post table and wp_ai1ec_events table to get the result.

Here is the sample query. If you want you can change the query to join table.

e.start will be today's datetime. Pass it as a string.

Here is Custom Query to get events which start today.

```
    $query = "Select * FROM wp_posts as p, wp_ai1ec_events as e where e.post_id = p.ID AND e.start = '2013-12-09 10:15:00'";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
print_r($results);
```

Comment: Any suggestions.. I need help querying the posts events by the current date.. so only show events for the current day